# Fabricjs width and getWidth()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an algorithm which is rendering an object with width and height. But when I use `setWidth()` that object doesn't actually get that width, it somehow gets something like x2 of the width I gave it. Check the code below:

```
    var width = canvas.getWidth();
    obj.setWidth(width);
    obj.setCoords();
    console.log(obj.getWidth());
    console.log(obj.width);
```

First log has wrong width "x2" and the second log has the correct width.

Comment: Is the object a circle? You could be passing it a radius.

Comment: object is group actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've struggled with similar stuff, and so I've tested (with fabricjs 1.6.2) and found out that for `fabric.Rect` `rect.width` is not equal to `rect.getWidth()`

`rect.width` gives the width not considering the rect's `strokeWidth`

`rect.getWidth()` considers the rect's `strokeWidth`

Also remember that the stroke is painted by default half inside the object's edge and half outside of it, thus for example `strokeWidth` of 10 enlarges the rect's perceived size by `5 + 5 = 10` pixels.

Hope this helps.